# What is the difference between ACL and SCO Link in Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth

ACL= Asynchronous Connection-Less. SCO = Synchronous Connection Oriented.

SCO is Point to Point Connection between only one master and only one slave.

ACL is multipoint connection between one master and many slaves.

What are the other differences?

Answer (score 18):

SCO is for real-time narrow band signal which does not require retransmission. Voice data in Bluetooth hands free kit is an example for this. This narrow band audio is called "Bluetooth voice" type. Where as ACL is for all other BT data transfer including High quality audio/video data. Example is music playback through A2DP. This is high bandwidth data and hence called "Advanced Audio". SCO is fixed bandwidth channels and can have maximum 3 channels per device, but throughput of ACL varies with other active connections(SCO and ACL) at that time.

Answer (score 6):

ACL: It is used exclusively to transport data.
     Retransmission based on ARQ. Available types DMx(Moderate rate), DHx(High data rate). where x=1,3,5

SCO: It is mainly used for Voice Communication (or data and voice combined). No retransmissions.HV1,HV2,HV3 are different types of voice packets possible. each with different encoding scheme.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the following diagram from my favorite conceptual guide to Bluetooth functionality.

Like Abin said, SCO is primarily utilized when a contiguous, real-time signal is required, like during a phone call.

ACL is for everything else, and is the primary mediating protocol for most data-transmission use-cases.

[image: http://www.althos.com/tutorial/Bluetooth-tutorial-protocol-layers.html]

Answer (score 0):

SCO ==>

SCO provides a circuit switched connection, where a dedicated, point-to-point link is established between the master device and the slave device before communication starts.
SCO is a symmetric link, i.e. fixed slots are allocated for each direction.
SCO radio links are used for time critical data transfer, mainly voice data.
A master device can support three SCO links with the same or different slaves. A slave device can have a maximum of three SCO links with its master device.
The focus is minimization of time latency.
The maximum data rate of SCO link is 64,000 bps (bits per second).
Packet retransmissions are not allowed, for assuring real-time transfer of voice traffic.
Forward Error Correction (FEC) is applied for data reliability.

ACL ==>

ACL is a packet oriented link, i.e. the link establishes a packet –    switched network. Both symmetric and asymmetric traffic are    supported. The master device controls the bandwidth of the ACL link.    ACL is used for transmission of data traffic which are delivered at    irregular intervals. One master device which connects with maximum    seven slave devices via ACL links to form a Piconet. The main    objective is to maintain data integrity rather than time latency. The    maximum data rates of ACL links can reach a 57.6 Kbps in downlink and    721 bps in uplink. Packet retransmissions are allowed to ensure data    integrity. Both FEC as well as Backward Error Correction with    retransmissions are adopted for data reliability.